# Laravel error with .htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, homestead

I guess I've a problem with my .htacces file in my laravel project that I"m trying to put online.

I've worked locally with homestead (first time I build a project with that).

This is what I have in my homestead.yaml file:

```
>  - map: domain.dev
>       to: /home/vagrant/Code/domain
```

but now the only route that works is this route:

> /

When I started my project I've changed some things so I didn't had to put:

> /public

After my domain name. This is my file structure now:

[image]

And my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The exact error is:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /admin/tickets was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

EDIT:

ERROR LOG:

```
[Fri Jan 08 2016] [:error] [pid 152074] [client ] File does not exist: /home/ev/public_html/domain.nl/local/index.php
[Fri Jan 08  2016] [authz_core:error] [pid ] [client ] A1630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ev/public_html/domain.nl/local/.htaccess
```

Comment: Um, where is your `public` directory?

Comment: Please read my question again.

Comment: Then where's your `index.php` and your `.htaccess`? I don't use Homestead, and so could very well be missing something here... What I do know is that no matter what environment you're running in, `public` is meant to be your document root.

Comment: That;s because those files are hidden on my mac. But I've set everything back to Laravel original file structure.

Comment: Did you fix this? How did you upload your files?

Comment: I would stick with the default structure.

Answer (score 0):

try to put app and other directory outside public_html file

more reference: 
https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.bvmnzz5eu

http://laravel.io/forum/06-07-2014-deploying-laravel-project-to-shared-hosting-server

Comment: Thanks, but could you please take a look at my edit?